# I can't get Text from the class, it returns null

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, webdriver

help me please i have two problems:

1) First i need equal the texts from Alert pop-up from:

```
<div class="noty_message message"><span class="noty_text">Uh oh! Email or password is incorrect</span></div>
```

My code:

```
var loginAlert = element(by.className('noty_text'));
expect(loginAlert.getAttribute('text')).toEqual("Uh oh! Email or password is incorrect")
```

But i get every time error:
Expected null to equal 'Uh oh! Email or password is incorrect'.

In first case i also tried find by getText()

2) The problem is in missed space, but i don't know how to add correct space

From:

```
 <span class="tooltip-text">Uh oh! This<br>isn’t an email</span>
```

My code:

```
var newInvalidEmail =  invalidEmail.getText().then(function (text) {
        expect(text.replace(/\n/, '')).toBe("Uh oh! This isn't an email");
    });
    expect(newInvalidEmail).toEqual("Uh oh! This isn't an email")
```

Error message:
    Expected 'Uh oh! Thisisn’t an email' to be 'Uh oh! This isn't an email'.

Comment: are you sure you are doing this correctly?  element(by.className('noty_text'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

01- You have to use `getText()` or `getAttribute("innerText")` , make sure that you have only one element has `noty_text` class name, also if not working try to wait before finding the element.

```
var loginAlert = element(by.className('noty_text'));
expect(loginAlert.getText()).toEqual("Uh oh! Email or password is incorrect")
```

2- Just add space in second param in replace function instead of empty string `replace(/\n/, ' '))`

```
var newInvalidEmail =  invalidEmail.getText().then(function (text) {
        expect(text.replace(/\n/, ' ')).toBe("Uh oh! This isn't an email");
    });
    expect(newInvalidEmail).toEqual("Uh oh! This isn't an email")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! in first case getAttribute("innerText") helped. In Second case your advice with space helped me. But now i getting Expected undefined to equal 'Uh oh! This isn't an email'. I think it is because of <br> tag, but i also have tried by innerText.